# Как использовать прокси локально?

Tags: node.js, proxy, chromium, puppeteer

Вопрос такой - как я могу локальному поднять несколько прокси? Дело в том, что запущен скрипт puppeteer и скорость очень маленькая за счёт установленной мной задержкам - так как при отсутствии задержкам вылезает капча. Хочу запустить несколько потоков на разных прокси. Какие есть варианты реализации?

Answer (score 1):

Вариант для запуска экземпляра `browser`, работающего через proxy:

```
puppeteer.launch({ args: ['--proxy-server="socks5://myproxy:8080'] });
```

---

И можно сделать interceptor в каждом экземпляре `page`, ведь это позволяет не создавать новый экземпляр `browser` в случае использования нескольких proxy.

Есть несколько интересных библиотек, позволяющих это сделать. Мне понравилась [puppeteer-page-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-page-proxy)

Простейшее применение - проксирование всех запросов со страницы:

```
const useProxy = require('puppeteer-page-proxy');

await useProxy(page, 'http://127.0.0.1:80');
```

Пример более селективного подхода:

```
const useProxy = require('puppeteer-page-proxy');

await page.setRequestInterception(true);
page.on('request', async request => {
    if (request.resourceType() === 'image') {
        request.abort();
    } else {
        await useProxy(request, 'socks4://127.0.0.1:1080');
    }
});
```

В качестве альтернативны можно предложить библиотеку [ppspider](https://github.com/xiyuan-fengyu/ppspider), она максимально заточена на использование [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript), но, увы, документация у неё скудная и китайскоязычная, но разобраться по исходникам не сложно.